# javascript slider settimeout issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently developing a small website for an architect.
My goal to achive is to make the side as simple as possible.

Therefore, I created the site as a one-page site. You can browse through the different subpages without a reload and without the use of php. just HTML5 and CSS3.

But the client wants the projects to be slideable.
Luckily I found a suitable slider on w3 (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

Was the simplest on I could found with prev and next buttons, auto-slide and using vanilla JS.
You can browse through the projects while using the slider. 
The content just uses a litte space in the foreground and a picture of the project replaces the whole background of the website.
But it uses setTimeout, which is driving me crazy.

Everything works perfect, as long as the user doesn't hit the next or prev button. Ten the slideshow is going crazy. (For sure, this issue is quite common and there a few threads here on stackoverflow, but i couldn't find a suitable answer for my project!)

I tried a few things, but I'm not very good in JavaScript.

```
<script>
"use strict";
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
 var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex;}
 if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1;} 
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length;}
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none"; 
 }
 x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
 setTimeout(showDivs, 8000); // Change image every 8 seconds
}
</script>
```

That's the code I'm using currently.
Is there any way to reset the timer after each slide?
I've read about clearTimeout but couldn't get it to work properly.

Any help is appreciated. thanks guys.

Comment: `setTimeout` returns time ID which you can use to `clearTimeout` (and potentionally start new one).

In your case you need to set global variable (e.g. `var timeoutId = null`) outside of `showDivs` function, call setTimeout as `timeoutId = setTimeout(showDivs, 8000);` and do `if (timeoutId) {clearTimeout(timeoutId)}` in `plusDivs` callback.

But I would also recommend you consider using slider library (e.g. Slick) and all your setup will look like: `$('.mySlides').slick();`

Comment: thanks for your fast answer.
This gave me a better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the timeout you set at the end of `showDivs`

```
<script>
"use strict";
var slideIndex = 1;
var timeOutId;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    // Stop the timeout from triggering.
    clearTimeout(timeOutId);

    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex;}
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1;} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length;}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    // Schedule a new timeout.
    timeOutId = setTimeout(showDivs, 8000); // Change image every 8 seconds
}
```

Comment: By the way, the problem was the setTimeout. It will trigger after 8 seconds of running the `showDivs` method. So the timeout gets set in the `showDivs(slideIndex)` at the start of your script. The `plusDivs` also calls the `showDivs` method. If you don't clear the timeout you get an additional timeout for each call to `showDivs`. This can lead to some really strange visual behaviour as the timeouts will occur seemingly at random.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so you need to change your code to store the timeout into a variable so you can cancel it.

```
var timer;
function showDivs (n) {
  /* the code */
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setTimeout(showDivs, 8000);
}
```

Comment: this seems to work,too.
just didn't know where to call the clearTimeout function